# jQuery-To Jquery from javascript

Tags: jquery

What is equivalent to

```
var input = document.getElementById("images"),
input.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {});
```

in jQuery?

Comment: All you're looking for, took me 10 seconds to Google both of them. `get element by id in jQuery` and `change event with jquery`....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#images').on("change",function(evt){

});
```

[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) should be your first option, if your jquery is < v1.7 then you can use [`bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) instead.

For further references: Check the [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/).

Comment: It says Uncaught TypeError: Object #images has no method 'on'

Comment: Then your jquery version is too old and you can use `bind` instead.

Comment: it definitely works: http://jsfiddle.net/pd7wv/ Do you have some other code occupying the `$`? try `jQuery` instead of `$`. Test this: `$().jquery` - it should give you the jquery version number.

Comment: Even without domready, it should not throw an error. The Set might be empty, but it's still a query object possessing the `on` method.

Comment: @Midhun apparently you fixed the problem - what exactly was it?

Comment: I haven't fixed the problem yet. But I know that you have given the right route for me.There is something missing in my code.I am not getting what it is. I am thinking to ask some of my seniors who can help me live.

Answer (score 2):

```
var input = $('#images')

input.bind("change",function(evt){

});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use

```
$('#images').change(function(evt) {

});
```